# Responsive image gallery solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I would like to ask about responsive galleries.

That's an example what I want to do. So, as you see, the image's size is not fixed. It is just thumbnail with saved proportions.
[image]

I am not sure how it works. How should I make mine responsive?

How should it be done? If there are some ready solution, please tell me about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use masonary library http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said you can use masonry

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/193/

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.gallery').masonry({
  itemSelector: 'img',
   columnWidth: 1,
});
```

Or you can try to do something with flexbox like this

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/194/

**CSS**

```
img {
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Or you can use `column` but i think support is pretty bad for this one

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/197/

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But its is not what i need :) Look at picture please. As you see the gaps between images are the same and still it is perfectly fited in container.

Answer (score 0):

http://masonry.desandro.com/ Is pretty much what you gona need.